# Make a reference to an element created via the jquery wrapInner function

Tags: jquery

I'm wrapping some elements using the jQuery wrapInner function. Like this.

```
$( "#container" ).wrapInner( "<div></div>" );
```

But I want to know the best way make a reference to this newly created div.  I was hoping I could just do

```
var featuresWrap = $( "#container" ).wrapInner( "<div></div>" );
```

But this just creates a reference to "#container".  So is this best way just to do the following?

```
$( "#container" ).wrapInner( "<div></div>" );
var featuresWrap = $( "#container div" );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `wrapInner` causes the element to have one *immediate* child, you can simply do:

```
var featuresWrap = $("#container").wrapInner("<div>").children();
```

to get the jQuery object associated with the created div.

In order to get the associated `HTMLElement`, simply do:

```
var htmlElement = featuresWrap.get(0);
```

Comment: Nice one.  Means I can have that one less line of code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
var featuresWrap = $( "#container > div" );
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan for the reply, but this is basically the same as what I already had.  Was after dropping that line completely which Joel's answer has allowed me to do.  Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Same result in the end, but with an additional line. which is what I had but without the child selector that you've used.  With Joel's I can just use the single line "var featuresWrap = $("#container").wrapInner("<div>").children();"